# How to search within folders in Firefox Bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, search, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

Is there any way or addon that allows the user to search for bookmarks within certain folders.  As of now if you use the search bark in bookmarks it will show results from all folders.  This is quite annoying and I would like to organized my "Unsorted Bookmarks" folder without pulling results from every organized folder I have.

Comment: The instructions at the end of this section appear to be out of date. I could not get them to work in Firefox 35: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sorting_and_rearranging_bookmarks_-_Firefox#Viewing_bookmarks_in_the_Bookmarks_Manager_or_Library_window